# filling an array with a loop in python

Tags: python

my problem is as follows, i have an array named `crave=['word1','word2','word3'....'wordx']` and i want to transform into `ITEM=[['word1','word2','word3'],['word4','word5','word6'] etc]` 
i used the following code

```
buff=[['none','none','none']]
n=10
ITEM=[]
i=0
while 1>0 :


 buff[0][0]=crave[i]
 buff[0][1]=crave[i+1]
 buff[0][2]=crave[i+2]
 ITEM.insert(len(ITEM),buff[0])
 i=i+3
 if i>n:
      break
```

but what i get instead is `[['wordx-2','wordx-1','wordx'],['wordx-2','wordx-1','wordx'],['wordx-2','wordx-1','wordx']etc]`
why does this happen ?:(

Comment: so you want to split the list into 3 elements sublists? is ther ordering important?

Comment: I tried to understand what your code does, I had to change some lines as to get it compile and run. Here's what I made of it: https://ideone.com/bHuDx2

Comment: Yes ordering is important Moj

Answer (score 10):

You can easily do this by using list comprehension. 
`xrange(0, len(crave), 3)` is used to iterate from 0 to len(crave) with an interval of 3. and then we use [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) `crave[i:i+3]` to extract the required data.

```
crave=['word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7']

ITEM = [crave[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(crave), 3)]

print ITEM
>>> [['word1', 'word2', 'word3'], ['word4', 'word5', 'word6'], ['word7']]
```

Comment: Interesting, especially the processing of the last ("broken") triple - it really works :-) https://ideone.com/S9AQF7

Comment: Thanks for appreciation @Wolf

Answer (score 4):

try to this.

```
crave = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', 'word7']
li = []
for x in range(0, len(crave), 3):
    li.append(crave[x:x+3])
print li
```

Comment: ...[list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) explained ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
In [10]: a =np.arange(20)

In [11]: a
Out[11]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])

In [12]: np.array_split(a,len(a)/3)
Out[12]: 

[array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([ 8,  9, 10]),
 array([11, 12, 13]),
 array([14, 15, 16]),
 array([17, 18, 19])]
```

Answer (score 1):

In respect to the question of "why does this happen":

The problem is that buff[0] is being referenced by the .insert, not copied. Hence on the next turn of the loop when buff changes anything that references buff will also change.

To do an explicit copy use list(). E.g.

```
 ITEM.insert(len(ITEM),list(buff[0]))
```